# Looking for C# - Java feature equivalence cheat sheet

Tags: c#, java

I'm looking for a resource that should help C# developer learning Java. I would like to have a fast reference that says, for instance:

```
C#               |      Java          | Suggested alternative
Extension Method |      NA            |  ...
Attributes       |    Annotations     |  ...
```

such a cheat sheet would be great resource in order to me, because he would help to break a thin barrier between the two world.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Language Syntax Diff-Sheet Between Java and C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762570/language-syntax-diff-sheet-between-java-and-c)

Comment: If the goal is to actually *learn* Java, then don't try to cross-reference everything against a C# checklist. That will just make you a C# developer writing Java. Look for the features you need in Java if you need them in Java. Don't just think "how would I do this in C#", and then look for a list of "how to convert C# features to Java".

Comment: @jalf probably you are right, anyway the meaning of "suggested alternative" should help avoiding "CSharpisms"

Comment: @Nacereddine don't know if it is a duplicate, I'm not talking about just Syntax, but language features, that is a little more extensive.

Comment: BTW With Lombok you get extension methods in java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [Comparison of C Sharp and Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Java) (But it's missing the Suggested alternative ;-))
- [Java and C# Comparison](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/java_csharp_comparison.html) ([PDF version](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/102242605/java-vs-C-comparison))
- [C# and Java: Comparing Programming Languages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms836794.aspx)
- [Moving to C# and the .NET Framework, for Java Developers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6073)
- Maybe a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762570/language-syntax-diff-sheet-between-java-and-c)

Comment: +1 it seems a good starting point, a little to much divulgative, it says for instance: Thread local variables : Yes, but *how to* ?

Comment: probably the closest one is http://cse.spsu.edu/jchastin/Transitioning/

Answer (score 1):

Conversion tools are available - though I don't know if it's exactly what you are looking for - you could try either http://twigletsoftware.com/ or http://tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/CSharp_to_Java_Converter_Details.html

Alternatively, for help with bridging the two languages together, take a look at http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html

Comment: tanks for the reply, yeah I mean something to *learn* the language by bridging the gap, a conversion tool is something more pragmatic

Comment: Ok, well in that case maybe these links could help you a little better - http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html and http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/java_csharp_comparison.html

Comment: the 25hoursday... could be the candidate for the answer, should be refactored as a cheat sheet

Comment: Ok glad it has helped, I've put the link into the answer in-case anyone else has a similar question to yourself in future.